# Use addMethod in jQuery Validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to validate a text box using jQuery Validate plugin's custom validation method (addMethod) but my code doesn't work.  Can anyone help me to find the error?  I have never used custom validation method before so it's bit hard for me to find where I went wrong in this code.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  // where to display the error relative to the element
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      error.appendTo(element.parent().find('div.myErrors'));
     }
 });

 jQuery.validator.addMethod(
"selectnic"
function(value,element){
if(element.value == /^[0-9]{9}[vVxX]$/)
   return false;
   else return true;
},
"wrong nic number"
); 



    $('#basicDetails').validate({ // initialize the Plugin
        rules: {
                fname: {
                    required: true,
                    lettersonly: true,
                },
                lname: {
                    required: true,
                    lettersonly: true,
                },  
            },
        messages: {
           fname: {
                required:"Please enter your first name",
                lettersonly: "Login format not valid",

            },
             lname: {
                required:"Please enter your last name",
                lettersonly: "Login format not valid",  
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { 
            alert('valid form submitted'); 
            return false; 
        }
    });

});
```

..html code ....

```
<form action="#" method="post"  id="basicDetails" runat="server">

 <table width="68%" border="0" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="6">


 <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td> First name </td>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="textbox" placeholder="Required field"/><div class="myErrors"></div></td> &nbsp;
                                    <td align="right"> Last name&nbsp; :</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="lname" class="textbox" id="lname" placeholder="Required field"/><div class="myErrors"></div></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td width="147" > NIC no </td>
                                    <td> : </td>
                                    <td width="172"><input type="text" name="nic" id="nic"   class="textbox"  placeholder="Required field"/><div class="myErrors"></div></td>
                                    <td width="167" align="right">Passport no &nbsp; :</td>
                                    <td width="167" id="showPP"> <input type="text" name="passport" class="textbox" id="ppnu" placeholder="Required field"/></td>    
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Submit "class="submit"   id="submit" />&nbsp; &nbsp;
                                    <input type="submit" name="reset"  value="Reset "class="reset" />
                                    </td>                                
                                </tr>


 </table>





</form>
```

.....after editing my code  ....

```
$(document).ready(function () {



jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  // where to display the error relative to the element
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      error.appendTo(element.parent().find('div.myErrors'));
     }
 });

 jQuery.validator.addMethod("selectnic", function(value, element){
    if (/^[0-9]{9}[vVxX]$/.test(value)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    };
}, "wrong nic number"); 


    $('#basicDetails').validate({ // initialize the Plugin


        rules: {
                fname: {
                    required: true,
                    lettersonly: true,
                        },
                lname: {
                    required: true,
                    lettersonly: true,
                    },

                 nicnumber: {
                            // other rules,
                        selectnic: true // <-  declare the rule someplace!
                            }


            },


        messages: {

           fname: {
                required:"Please enter your first name",
                lettersonly: "Login format not valid",

            },
             lname: {
                required:"Please enter your last name",
                lettersonly: "Login format not valid",

            },
        },


        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Where is the HTML markup for this form?

Comment: I can see a syntax error, you have missed `,` after `selectnic`. Also what's the point of comparing a string to a regex?

Comment: @ Sparky html code is bit long to add here

Comment: I did not say to add _all_ of the HTML markup.  Only add the _relevant parts of the form_… the opening/closing `form` tags and all of the `input` elements including the `button`.

Comment: @ Sparky  I added my code

Comment: @ Undefined  here I wanted to validate NIC number  in a textbox the regular expression to check NIC number is used here

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There are three different issues as outlined by the progressing edits below.

---

1)
You missed a comma just between `selectnic` and the `function(`.

Also, try this format instead when using `regex`...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("selectnic", function(value, element){
    if (/^[0-9]{9}[vVxX]$/.test(value)) {
        return false;  // FAIL validation when REGEX matches
    } else {
        return true;   // PASS validation otherwise
    };
}, "wrong nic number");
```

**EDIT**:  This answer assumes your original `regex` and logic are both correct.  Your logic returns `false` when the `regex` is a match.  `false` means that validation failed and you will see the error message.

---

2) **EDIT 2:**

After creating new methods, you also have to *use* them.  I do not see the `selectnic` rule/method used anyplace in your code.

**Example**:

```
rules: {
    myFieldName: {
        // other rules,
        selectnic: true // <-  declare the rule someplace!
    }
}
```

---

3) **EDIT 3:**

And finally, the OP's original `true/false` logic was backwards.  He wanted to PASS validation upon a regex match… therefore, needs to `return true`.

```
    if (/^[0-9]{9}[vVxX]$/.test(value)) {
        return true;   // PASS validation when REGEX matches
    } else {
        return false;  // FAIL validation
    };
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/DzvNr/**

Comment: @Erandi, simply saying "it didn't work" is incredibly unhelpful to everyone.  What didn't work?  What troubleshooting did you perform?  What errors are showing in your console?  **Are you sure _your_ regex is correct?  Is _your_ logic correct?  Your function will return `false` (FAIL validation) when the `regex` IS a match.**

Comment: @ Sparky regex is correct here what I want is when user enter a NIC number it checks whether entered number has  '804567789V' format (9 numbers and last letter can be 'x' or 'y' ) and using normal jQuery validation plugin I can't do this so I used custom validation method but here after adding this code I tried but it doesn't show any error message

Comment: @Erandi, you defined your new rule but you don't use it anyplace.  How is the plugin supposed to know which `input` to evaluate your `"selectnic"` method?  See my latest edit above.

Comment: @ Sparky  please tell me can we use any name instead of this  "myFieldName"

Comment: @Erandi, seriously?  I guess you didn't try it.  It says "EXAMPLE", so yes, `myFieldName` means that you would *insert **your own*** field name.

Comment: @ Sparky  My filed name is "nicnumber"  i used it and after that checked it. error message for first name and last name appears but not for the text filed of  nic number

Comment: @Erandi, Like I said before, I think your `true/false` logic is backwards.  When I swap it, it works:  http://jsfiddle.net/DzvNr/

Comment: @Erandi, please just slow down a bit in the future and read [this site's FAQ sections](http://stackoverflow.com/help).  My very first comment above specifically asked you if the `true/false` logic was backwards and I even made comments in the code explaining that it would fail validation when the regex matched.  Anyway, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution including Greek characters.

```
$.validator.addMethod('alphabet', function (value, element) {

        let regExName = /^[A-Za-zΑ-Ωα-ωίϊΐόάέύϋΰήώ]+$/;
        return (regExName.test(value));

    }, 'There are non alphabetic characters!');
```

```
  $("#orderForm").validate({
     rules: {
          first_name: {
             required: true,
             alphabet: true
          }
});
```