# Regex for JQuery Age Validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm trying to perform age validation using jQuery and RegEx, but it doesn't seem to work.  I've tried two different tries at RegEx - with the one commented out in my code below. I'm trying to show an error if the age entered is less than 16 using the following code:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("ageCheck",
function (value, element) {
    //var age = /^([1-9]\d|[6-9]\d{2})$/;
    var age = /^(1[6789]|[2-9]\d)$/;
    return this.optional(element) || age.test(value);

},
"Age must be greater than or equal to 16"
```

);

Comment: Why are you using a regex for this?

Comment: it was easier to just `age = parseInt(value)` and do `if (age >= 16)`

Comment: I thought it would be easier as I'm using RegEx for phone number and postal code above in my code.

Comment: But there is no problem with the regex here.

Comment: by the way that was the best practice to better factor your logic... anyway you still may deserve an answer here to get why your regex didnt work

Comment: @DiegoDeVita Tried using `jQuery.validator.addMethod("ageCheck",
    function (value, element) {
        age = parseInt(value);
        if (age >= 16) {
            return this.optional(element) || age.test(value);
        }


    }, "You must be at least 16 years of age.");` but it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

In the comments I tried to suggest you a better way to deal with the validation of the age value instead of using regular expressions.

Unfortunately you didn't include any clue on what didn't work in a more granular manner and in your question you only included a small part of the whole picture.

So I can't say what you are doing wrong because you didn't share anything in details. But I can just add what you are missing around your custom defined validator.

So this is a working example having your age field inside a form that you can submit and for which you can see the error message if any. The validation will be triggered anytime the input text loses its focus. So no need to force the submit to see it in action.

And here is some reference I used to learn about the plugin:

- https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/
- https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/
- [Use addMethod in jQuery Validate plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658228/use-addmethod-in-jquery-validate-plugin)

```js
//on document ready
$(document).ready(function() {

  //defines your custom validator called ageRangeValidation
  $.validator.addMethod(
    'ageRangeValidation',
    ageCheck,
    'Age must be greater than or equal to 16'
  );

  //initializes the validation for the given form
  $('#myform').validate({ 
    //rules
    rules: {
      age: {
        //including your custom defined validator bound to the age field here
        ageRangeValidation: true
      }
    }
  });
 
});

//your validation logic for the age field
const ageCheck = (value, element) => {
    if (parseInt(value) >= 16)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
}
```

```css
.error{
  color: red;
  font-style: italic;
  display: block;
}

button[type='submit']{
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" id="age" name="age"/>
  <label id="age-error" class="error" for="age"></label>
 
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```